# Why does console.log(document.getElementById( 'blah' ))) give different log messages in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am just messing around and am logging out a div that I have selected with standard javascript but that I have executed inside a jQuery document.ready(fn) block.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log(document.getElementById( 'blah' ));
})
```

I'm really interested to know why sometimes I get...

```
<div id="blah"></div>
```

And other times I get...

[image]

Seems to log differently randomly.

Comment: Can you provide the exact code and/or fiddles to demonstrate this behavior? Also are you seeing it consistently across multiple browsers?

Comment: I'm just writing it out using a console.log you can see it displayed...

Comment: You've got to tell us which web browser this question is about.

Comment: I removed the [tag:jQuery] tag - this question would be exactly the same without jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does appear to be random, at least in Chrome. If you want to force it one way or another in the Chrome console you can use **console.dir** and **console.dirxml**.

- **console.dirxml** will force the output to be like your first example, in xml format
- **console.dir** will output like your second example, in object notation.

More examples of console commands in Chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api

Edit: **dirxml** also works in Internet Explorer 11 and later but not in Firefox though this shouldn't be an issue as Firefox outputs elements in xml format.

Comment: okay this has been the most helpful answer as you actually explained what the difference is too! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Each environment decides on how to present objects:

```
FireFox/Firebug:  <div id="blah">

IE/Developer tools:   [object HTMLDivElement]
```